# Why am i getting the same predictions with my new data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

This is a random forest model in r. It is a football prediction model which is based on ladbroke odds. It predicts full time results(FTR) of matches.

```
 zmodel <- randomForest(traindata$FTR ~ traindata$LBH + traindata$LBD + traindata$LBA)
```

I've tried making prediction on the train data itself using

```
 predict(zmodel,newdata = traindata)
```

Then, i've made prediction on a new test data.

```
predict(zmodel,newdata = testdata)
```

I am getting same prediction results though the test data and train data are different. What am i doing wrong?

Is it possible to make predictions on data that do not have the same number of rows as in the train data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have correctly split your data into training and testing datasets (with different observations).  It is worth checking this.

Instead of:

```
zmodel <- randomForest(traindata$FTR ~ traindata$LBH + traindata$LBD + traindata$LBA)
```

Try:

```
 zmodel <- randomForest(FTR ~ LBH + LBD + LBA, data = traindata)
```

This will work with training and test data sets of different lengths.  For example:

```
predictForest1 = predict(zmodel, newdata = traindata)
predictForest2 = predict(zmodel, newdata = testdata)
```